# Correct PHP credentials for database leads to error signifying wrong credentials

Tags: php, database

I create a database called 'demo'.
I set a username called 'username'.
I set a password called 'password'.
I connect to the database.
I run the following:

```
<?php
    define ('DB_NAME', 'demo');
    define ('DB_USER', 'username');
    define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
    if (!$db_selected){
        die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    ?>
```

And I get the following errors.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\index.php on line 101
>   Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am beyond confused. I'm using the correct username and password, but still it doesn't connect, any ideas where the problem might lie?

Comment: because you are entering wrong credentials

Comment: I think that you missing the step that gives correct permissions to the user and database. You can write what there are in 101 line of your code?

Comment: You can see I'm entering the correct credentials..
This is the 101st line         $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
P.s. When I try this without a password it works.. But I'd like to have a password

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes I think I am missing that step, but I don't know where to find it.. I'll look for it

Comment: If without password it works, your user haven't assigned a password. Is not PHP problem, is a MySQL missconfiguration. Theese are the steps: 1) create database. 2) Create user. 3) Give permissions to the user applied to the database. 4) Connect and enjoy.

Comment: If this is a new project, you should probably not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and should be replaced with either PDO or `mysqli`. The next major of PHP will not have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this credentials are correct? Alternatively, have this user permissions to do this?

If your user hasn't a password see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html)

```
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] = password_option

password_option: {
    PASSWORD('auth_string')
  | OLD_PASSWORD('auth_string')
  | 'hash_string'
}
```

Example

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Permission can be set with [Grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

```
GRANT ALL ON demo.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Yes there is a password, it is 'password'. How do I set user permissions?

Comment: I have updated my post with Grant that permit to set permissions

Answer (score 1):

You may have to give [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) permissions to that user on MySQL database